# Select2 retrieve ajax url

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I created a select2 with ajax.

```
const select2Initialized = $('#myselect').select2({
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://nixarsoft.com/',
      dataType: 'json'
    }
})
```

I want to access `url` property from `select2Initialized` variable. Is it possible? I searched google but not found any good result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to do that because you can store the options in an variable and access it later like this:

```
const options = {
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://nixarsoft.com/',
    dataType: 'json'
  }
}
const select2Initialized = $('#myselect').select2(options);
console.log(options.ajax.url);
```

But if you still want to get url from `select2Initialized`, you can do something like:

```
select2Initialized.data('select2').options.options.ajax.url
```

Comment: Oh yes you're right. Probably my brain is gone away. Sometimes programmers can miss some small things and they causes explosion of 125 million dollar space shuttle :D